# Python Regex Key Value Matching

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

I have a file I am trying to parse that includes key value pairs. Where the key starts with a "-" followed by alpha characters and the value proceeding it as depicted in the picture below.

When I parse the file with the below regex pattern I am easily able to get keys and values but when values include multiple words or quoted data (that also matches key value) my pattern matching is failing. I've tried multiple iterations of regex pattern matching but failing to get the desired output. I managed to find a regex pattern to match the quoted text'"(.*?)"' but unable to use both patterns at the same time. Any help to get the desired output below is much appreciated.

[image: Keys and Values]

**My Code (Desired results for first line only)**:

```
mystring = '''-desc none -type used -cost med -color blue
-desc none -msg This is a a message -name test
-desc "(-type old -cost high)" -color green'''

mydict = {}
item_num = 0
for line in mystring.splitlines():
    quoted = re.findall('"(.*?)"', line)
    key_value = re.findall('(-\w+\s+)(\S+)', line)
    print(key_value)

### Output ###
[('-desc ', 'none'), ('-type ', 'used'), ('-cost ', 'med'), ('-color ', 'blue')]
[('-desc ', 'none'), ('-msg ', 'This'), ('-name ', 'test')]
[('-desc ', '"(-type'), ('-cost ', 'high)"'), ('-color ', 'green')]

### Desired Output ###
[('-desc ', 'none'), ('-type ', 'used'), ('-cost ', 'med'), ('-color ', 'blue')]
[('-desc ', 'none'), ('-msg ', 'This is a message'), ('-name ', 'test')]
[('-desc ', "(-type old -cost high)"), ('-color ', 'green')]
```

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/YSw8Cr - does it work as expected?

Comment: This is amazing RegEx wizardry! Yes worked exactly as desired. Can you pelase provide some brief explanation of the regex pattern used here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best regex you could use:
*It's never too late to change your vote.*

**regex raw:**

```
(?<!\S)-(\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|[^\s"-]+(?:\s+[^\s"-]+)*)(?!\S)
```

**python raw**:

```
r"(?<!\S)-(\w+)\s+(\"[^\"]*\"|[^\s\"-]+(?:\s+[^\s\"-]+)*)(?!\S)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/7bYN1A/1

Key = group 1
Value = group 2

```
 (?<! \S )
 -
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 \s+ 
 (                             # (2 start)
      " [^"]* "
   |  [^\s"-]+ 
      (?: \s+ [^\s"-]+ )*
 )                             # (2 end)
 (?! \S )
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?<!\S)-(\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|[^\s"-]+(?:\s+[^\s"-]+)*)(?!\S)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   10
Elapsed Time:    1.66 s,   1660.05 ms,   1660048 µs
Matches per sec:   301,196
```

Comment: This is not including values with special characters like "\" and "\&". For example: "-desc n&one -type used -cost med -color bl\ue". Here is it is not matching "n&one" and "bl\ue".  Can it be updated to include special characters in values?

Comment: @MBasith - Are quotes considered a single value: `-this "quoted"` ? or can it be mixed in a value with other characters/quotes: `-that here"quoted"there"quoted"` ? Or can a value contain 1,2,3,4, .... different quotes ? If you don't know that's fine.

Comment: Quotes are considered a single value. Value will only contain a single pair of quotes.

Comment: This works great! Can I ask how you generated this? Was it through just general knowledge and experience of using RegEx or do you have some tool to help?

Comment: I use [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) to develop, test, maintain, benchmark regex. I have hundreds of regex files I've developed. Using this tool, cut down the learning time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(-\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|.*?)(?=$|\s*-\w+\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z82hcw/1).

**Details**

- `(-\w+)` - Group 1: `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `("[^"]*"|.*?)` - Group 2: `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then `"` or any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first ...
- `(?=$|\s*-\w+\s)` - end of string or 0+ whitespaces, `-`, 1+ word chars and a whitespace.

Regulex graph:

[image]

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YSw8Cr):

```
import re
mystring = '''-desc none -type used -cost med -color blue
-desc none -msg This is a a message -name test
-desc "(-type old -cost high)" -color green'''

mydict = {}
for line in mystring.splitlines():
    key_value = re.findall(r'(-\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|.*?)(?=$|\s*-\w+\s)', line)
    print(key_value)
```

Output:

```
[('-desc', 'none'), ('-type', 'used'), ('-cost', 'med'), ('-color', 'blue')]
[('-desc', 'none'), ('-msg', 'This is a a message'), ('-name', 'test')]
[('-desc', '"(-type old -cost high)"'), ('-color', 'green')]
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the detailed explanation and the visual!